# Can I serialize a closure to Vec<u8> then deserialize and execute it?

Tags: serialization, rust, closures

I want to do something like this pseudocode:

```rust
let mut vec = Vec<u8>::new();
vec.resize(1024); // Some large-enough size

serialize(&vec, || { .... });

// ... other code blah blah ...

deserialize(&vec); // This will execute the closure
```

Ideally, I would be able to run deserialize in another thread, which is the whole point of doing this really.

I do not want to send an opcode and data because this way opens up a remarkably clean programming model where you don't create messages and send them.  Instead you just run arbitrarily complex code in another thread.

Why "remarkably clean"?

1. There are no opcodes (messages) that need to be created. i.e., less code.
2. There is no switch statement for opcode dispatch on the receiving end. i.e., less code.
3. Since there is no *protocol*, there is no need to version the messages. i.e., less code.

This idea cannot be used across processes, but that's OK for my needs.

Comment: Uhm, interesting indeed. Are you sure you want to serialize the closure itself? why dont just serialize the data and a tag for the operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using `unsafe`? No. No no no.

The problem is that since `Vec<u8>`s can be trivially modified, you can easily violate Rust's safety invariants. Consider the following code:

```rust
let vec = Vec<u8>::new();
vec.resize(1024);
// Our theoretical serialize function.
serialize(&vec, || { /* ... */ });
vec[0] = 0x90; // What happens to the closure now?
deserialize(&vec); // There goes any memory safety...
```

However, if all you want to do is send closures between threads, consider using something like `std::sync::mpsc`, which supports sending closures:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

let (tx, rx) = channel();
thread::spawn(move || {
    tx.send(|| { "hi" }).unwrap();
});
let f = rx.recv().unwrap();
assert_eq!(f(), "hi");
```

My guess, however, is that this is not actually what you want to do. Like Netwave said in the comments, you most likely actually want to send the data and a tag of the operation; for example:

```rust
// On one thread...
tx.send((Op::REMOVE_FILE, path));
// and on the other thread...
let (op, path) = rx.recv();
match op {
  Op::REMOVE_FILE => remove_file(path),
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I completely agree that this heads straight into "unsafe" territory.  Please see my blurb above that should hopefully answer why I'm looking to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: I will check out mpsc though!